# Need optimal regex code to eliminate repeat sentences

Tags: python, regex

I've come up with this code that matches up to a repeat of the three prior sentences. (It can be extended to any maximum number of repeat sentences by repeating the pattern.)

```
(.*?\.)( .*?\.)?( .*?\.)? \1\2?\3?
```

Example usage:

```py
string = 'Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion. Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion.'
output = re.sub(r'(.*?\.)( .*?\.)?( .*?\.)? \1\2?\3?', r'\1\2\3', string , flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(output)  # 'Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion.'
```

eg. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZEGyeI/1): `'Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion. Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion.'`

It works to match the repeat of one or two sentences too.

eg. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FV6Flg/1): `'Red apple. Red apple.'` -> Outputs `'Red apple.'`

eg.    [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRXZa7/1): `'Red apple. Green pepper. Red apple. Green pepper.'` -> Outputs `'Red apple. Green pepper.'`

Can you suggest an elegant/general form for making it match any nuber of repeat sentences?

Thank you.

Comment: How about [`([^.]*\.(?: [^.]*\.)*) \1`/`\1`](https://regex101.com/r/eXItqH/2)?

Comment: This is not really a regular expression problem.  You should split the paragraph into sentences (using `.split('. ')`, maybe), then put the results in a `set` (which will eliminate the duplicates).

Comment: @ InSync : your solution is elegant and excellent! Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into sentences and print it as a set:

```
import re
string = 'Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion. Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion.'
print( set( re.split('\. *', string)))
```

Output:

```
{'', 'Green pepper', 'Red apple', 'Yellow onion'}
```

Yes, the result loses the period.  Since we know each sentence ended with a period originally, it's pretty easy to add one.

Alternatively, without using regular expressions at all:

```
string = 'Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion. Red apple. Green pepper. Yellow onion.'
print( set( string.replace('. ','.').split('.')[:-1]))
```

Output:

```
{'Yellow onion', 'Green pepper', 'Red apple'}
```

Comment: [Split by `(?<=\.)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/WoSG8s/2) saves the dot and does not introduce any new empty strings.